# math library for half-precision numbers

Tags: c++, math.h, half-precision-float

I want to use half-precision arithmetic on Cortex-A76. I installed clang compiler to use _Float16 data type (which is for 16-bit arithmetic purpose).

I was wondering is there any library for half-precision mathematic functions? (like  for quadruple-precision numbers)
or which math functions are available for half-precision numbers? I checked the math.h library and there are functions just for double and float. Am I right?

Comment: These two might be of interest: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/12/half-precision-floating-point-format_14.html and http://half.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-May/053771.html
<<More controversially we also added a "synonym" for this using 'short float'
rather than '_Float16' (or OpenCL's 'half'), and created a parallel set of
the ISO C library functions using 's' to suffix the usual names (e.g. 'tan',
'tanf', 'tanl' plus 'tans').>>